# How to add all int32 element in a lane using neon intrinsic

Tags: c, arm, llvm, simd, neon

Here is my code for adding all int16x4 element in a lane:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
...
int16x4_t acc = vdup_n_s16(1);
int32x2_t acc1;
int64x1_t acc2;
int32_t sum;
acc1 = vpaddl_s16(acc);
acc2 = vpaddl_s32(acc1);
sum = (int)vget_lane_s64(acc2, 0);
printf("%d\n", sum);// 4
```

And I tried to add all int32x4 element in a lane.

but my code looks inefficient:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
...
int32x4_t accl = vdupq_n_s32(1);
int64x2_t accl_1;
int64_t temp;
int64_t temp2;
int32_t sum1;
accl_1=vpaddlq_s32(accl);
temp = (int)vgetq_lane_s64(accl_1,0);
temp2 = (int)vgetq_lane_s64(accl_1,1);
sum1=temp+temp2;
printf("%d\n", sum);// 4
```

Is there simply and clearly way to do this? I hope the LLVM assembly code is simply and clearly after compile it. and I also hope the final type of `sum` is 32 bits.

I used [ellcc](http://ellcc.org/) cross-compiler base on LLVM compiler infrastructure to compile it.

I saw the similar question([Add all elements in a lane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171117/add-all-elements-in-a-lane)) on stackoverflow, but the intrinsic `addv` doesn't work on my host.

Comment: Why do you feel your code looks inefficient? I see no complicated looping or branching.  Just sequential.  And is there a problem other than efficiency that you are trying to solve? i.e. does the code do what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Because LLVM assembly code is complicated after compile it, so I'd like to know is there easier way to do this such as an neon intrinsic.

Comment: The problem for my goal is auto generate LLVM-IR through a pass, it is difficult for me if the LLVM-IR code is complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want a 32-bit result, presumably either intermediate overflow is unlikely or you simply don't care about it, in which case you could just stay 32-bit all the way:

```
int32x2_t temp = vadd_s32(vget_high_s32(accl), vget_low_s32(accl));
int32x2_t temp2 = vpadd_s32(temp, temp);
int32_t sum1 = vget_lane_s32(temp2, 0);
```

However, using 64-bit accumulation isn't actually any more hassle, and can also be done without dropping out of NEON - it's just a different order of operations:

```
int64x2_t temp = vpaddlq_s32(accl);
int64x1_t temp2 = vadd_s64(vget_high_s64(temp), vget_low_s64(temp));
int32_t sum1 = vget_lane_s32(temp2, 0);
```

Either of those boils down to just 3 NEON instructions and no scalar arithmetic. The crucial trick on 32-bit ARM is that a pairwise add of two halves of a Q register is simply a normal add of two D registers - that doesn't apply to AArch64 where the SIMD register layout is different, but then AArch64 has the aforementioned horizontal `addv` anyway.

Now, how horrible any of that looks in LLVM IR I don't know - I suppose it depends on how it treats vector types and operations internally - but in terms of the final ARM machine code both could be considered optimal.

Comment: Your answer is helpful! There are `shufflevector` instructions instead of  type conversion instruction such as `trunc` or `sext` in my LLVM IR. Thanks a lot!